Add a metabox to admin WooCommerce Product if it has specific product tag
I am really struggling with WooCommerce PHP. This time I am simply trying to see if a product post has a tag before continuing to add a custom metabox. The code is written into functions.php of the child theme.
global $wp_query;
$id = $wp_query->post->ID;

if ( ! has_tag( "hasparts", $id )) {
    die; // used return also
    } else {
        // add metabox
}

I get the following error
Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiz_invent\wp-content\themes\storefront-child\functions.php on line 14
I do not seem to be able to get my head around how to find basic post properties (ID, SKU) or how and where to use $post variable.

You can use has_term to check if current post has term such as tag. Example:
has_term( 'hasparts', 'product_tag' )

Great this works! I am finding that examples given in books and tutorials are often simplified and working within WP and Woo life is more complicated!

StackOverflow is not only a great resource for getting help with WP and WooCommerce, but it’s also an excellent learning tool when used alongside their documentation. So whenever you have a problem or coding related question, try and make use of the search functionality, and you will learn really quick, I am sure. Welcome on board.

WooCommerce Tag is a custom taxonomy, so it will work with WordPress has_term() and product_tag taxonomy for WooCommerce tag.
Below is a complete example based on your requirement:
// Add a metabox to WooCommerce Product conditionally
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'admin_product_custom_metabox' );
function admin_product_custom_metabox() {

    if( has_term( array('hasparts'), 'product_tag') ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'custom',
            __('Custom Meta Box'),
            'custom_metabox_content_callback',
            'product',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }
}

// Metabox content callback function
function custom_metabox_content_callback() {
    echo 'Here goes the metabox content…';
}

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
